# mingw cross compiler won't link qt libs statically

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

I'm having trouble getting Qt to statically link its libraries when cross compiling from my Linux machine to windows. I added this to my config to make compile statically.

```
win32:CONFIG += -static
```

And by looking at the output of make it seems to have passed the flags correctly (omitting object files to make it short)

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads [exe and object files] /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libQt5Widgets.dll.a -ldwmapi -luxtheme /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libQt5Gui.dll.a -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -ljpeg -lpng -L/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz -lm -lintl -lglib-2.0 -lshlwapi -lpcre -lgraphite2 /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libQt5Core.dll.a -lz -lpcre2-16 -liconv -lversion -lnetapi32 -luserenv -lole32 -luuid -lwinmm -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32  /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libglu32.a /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libopengl32.a /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libgdi32.a /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a -lmingw32 /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libqt5main.a -lshell32
```

As you can see the static flags are being passed to the compiler correctly, however I tried running the resulting exe in both WINE, and on a windows machine but in both cases it tells me that it failed to find the Qt dlls. The wine error log had more info so that's the one im providing

```
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Core.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\zee\\mapper\\release\\mapper.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Gui.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\zee\\mapper\\release\\mapper.exe") not found
0009:err:module:import_dll Library Qt5Widgets.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\zee\\mapper\\release\\mapper.exe") not found
0009:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\zee\\mapper\\release\\mapper.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

I'm running on an Arch Linux machine with the latest qt5base aur package (5.13.1), and the latest mignw package (g++ 9.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler command line has both static and dynamic libraries. For instance: "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libQt5Core.dll.a" is the import library for the dynamic "Qt5Core.dll". The right file to be linked in static mode  would be "libQt5Core.a". Your problem looks similar to this report of the mingw project: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/4970